# Set-Location scope

Tags: powershell, scope, cd

Given this file

```sh
Set-Location C:\
```

If I run it

```
.\foo.ps1
```

It will change the directory in the script. However once the script is finished the parent console directory has also been changed. Can `Set-Location` be called in such a way as to affect only the running script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
try
{
     Push-Location
     Set-Location c:\
     # your code here ...
}

finally
{
     Pop-Location
}
```

Comment: I think this can be simplified to 
```powershell
try
{
     Push-Location c:\
}

finally
{
     Pop-Location
}
```